# In node.js programming, how do you handle the scenario where a callback doesn't fire?

Tags: node.js

A frequently used asynchronous function call idiom in node.js is to use callback functions like this:

```
library.doSomething(params, function(err,result) {
    if (err) {
        ... handle error, retry etc
    } else {
        ... process results, be happy!
    }
});
```

It's great - you call something, then later on handle the results or an error. There is unfortunately an excluded third option... that the code you've called never executes your callback. What are the best approaches to handle the possibility of a callback never getting called?

A lot of the time, especially if you're writing a library that relies on the network, you need to guarantee that you will call any callbacks passed to you once and only once. With that in mind, a pattern something like this looks like the way to go:

```
// set a timout
var failed = false, callbackFailure = setTimeout(function() {
    ... handle failure, call further pending callbacks with a timeout error
    failed = true;
},30000);

library.doSomething(params, function(err,result) {
    if (!failed) {
        clearTimeout(callbackFailure);
        if (err) {
            ... handle error, retry etc
        } else {
            ... process results, be happy again!
        }
    }
});
```

It seems like a matter of faith that any callback you expect to fire actually will fire, and I'm sure all programmers have run into scenarios where callbacks simply won't execute for whatever reason - cosmic rays, sunspots, network failures, bugs in a third party library, or ... *gasp* ... bugs in your own code.

Is something like my code example actually a good practice to adopt or has the node.js community already found a better way to handle it?

Comment: Eh, this is a silly question ( and not constructive ). It's like asking: can you guarantee that any code in any language works as it should? The answer is: you can't! Good administrator will monitor his application all the time. After all everything can fail due to "cosmic rays". This has **nothing** to do with Node.js. The engine is fine. It is tested heavily all the time.

Comment: Couldn't you just defensively use try{...}catch{...} blocks?

Comment: @freakish - node js has some shortcomings with regards to async error handling, this link seems pretty interesting. http://stella.laurenzo.org/2011/03/bulletproof-node-js-coding/

Comment: @LastCoder OP is asking for something different. What I've meant was that the engine is fine and it will always reach the callback ( either with success or error ). But OP is trying to ensure that. So going further, I guess that he would need to make sure that `try{...}catch{...}` block fires as well, because... you know, "cosmic rays". :D

Comment: @freakish - you're missing the point somewhat. This isn't about good administration practices, it's about robust asynchronous coding practices. A failed callback could create an intermittent failure that regular use by devs, testers or sysadmins wouldn't pick up.

I'm not saying I have a lack of faith in node.js specifically, but a lack of faith in the 100% correctness of any code. Every time a popular library or product has a new release you'll see bug fixes. If you're writing code that must not fail when it hits a bug that causes a callback not to fire how do you handle it?

Comment: @freakish Don't really understand your rather dismissive response to this question. It's a reasonable thing to ask about - what are some good defensive coding idioms when passing a callback to black box function you don't necessarily trust? e.g. I've found transient bugs in some db drivers where callbacks get left hanging and leak memory. Pragmatically it's reasonable to want to handle that scenario - its not always possible to fix the root cause. Next time, why not attempt to get to the bottom of someone's question rather than just dismissing it?

Comment: @tomtheguvnor It is always possible to fix the root cause. Either by you or creator ( whom you should contact when you see that he's library is leaking memory ). If you don't trust the library you are using, then why are you using it in the first place? Such "coding practice" is a waste of time. And also at the end of the day you will find out that in most cases you don't need it.

Comment: @tomtheguvnor I would like to see that driver which was leaking memory. We are talking about stable release, right? Not some alpha/beta?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where it's gone, but an answer popped in here and disappeared with a link to https://github.com/andyet/paddle - a small library designed to provide callback execution "insurance". At least it suggests I'm not the first person to have scratched my head regarding this problem.

From the docs on there is an anecdote validating the question somewhat:

> Node.js famously had an http client but where occasionally no callback
>   would occur for an HTTP request if the response was too fast. If I
>   wanted to make sure my http client callback occurred.

The example they give is a little more sophisticated than my example and can handle event based callbacks, enabling code to regularly "check in" as intermediate activity like an ondata handler fires and then trigger an error if it stops or times out.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    paddle.stop();
}, 12000);

var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
    var http_insurance = paddle.insure(function(res) {
        console.log("The request never had body events!");
        console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
        console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    }, 9, [res]);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
        http_insurance.check_in();
    });
});
req.end();
```

I'm answering my own question here, but I would still be interested to see if any other implementations, libraries or patterns exist to solve the same problem.

Comment: I've never heard about such thing as callback not firing, because response was too fast. :D This would imply serious bug in Node.js engine. And if that's the case, then I don't know how you can be sure that `setTimeout` callback will fire? You don't understand, it is impossible to ensure that and worrying about it is just a waste of time. And yes: it looks like you have a lack of faith in Node.js engine. Feel free to use other engines. Although I'm sure you won't be creating seperate thread per request just to make sure that the response have been received. :)

Comment: Anyway, if it makes you feel better, then feel free to accept your own answer.

Comment: @freakish - I don't know why you're having such a hard time accepting that a callback not firing is a problem that could exist. Nowhere have I stated that it has to be core node engine code that does this, it could be a branch missed in your code that fails to callback correctly or something similar in a library you use. 

Spotting which callback fails to fire and logging it is the first step to finding the fault and fixing it, whether in your own code or upstream.

Answer (score 1):

Not looking at paddle it seems easy enough to create callback execution insurance for badly written or debugged code.

A function like this:

```
// requireCB:
//   timeout - milliseconds before insurance gets used
//   cb - callback function to invoke normally or when insurance expires
function requireCB(timeout, cb) {
    var timeoutTimer;
    var canBeCalled = false;
    var myCB = function () {
        if (timeoutTimer) { clearTimeout(timeoutTimer); timeoutTimer = 0; }
        if (canBeCalled) { canBeCalled = false; cb.apply(this, arguments); }
    };
    timeoutTimer = setTimeout(function () { myCB(new Error('timed out')) }, timeout);
    canBeCalled = true;
    return myCB;
}
```

We create insurance widgets that can be used like so:

```
var rcb = requireCB(100, function (err, data1, data2) {
    console.log('called, err =', err, ', data1 =', data1, ', data2 =', data2);
});
functionExpectedToInvokeCallback(rcb);
```

Or in an actually immediately runnable example:

```
var rcb = requireCB(100, function (err, data) {  // set insurance for 0.1 seconds
    console.log('called, err =', err, ', data =', data);
});
setTimeout(function () { rcb(undefined, 'sheep') }, 1000);  // set normal callback in 1 second
```

Flip the timeout values to not trigger the insurance.

Comment: And likewise easy enough to add tracking data to your function to note how many times insurance gets used and even go and track if the callback is eventually called just how long it took so you know if you want to increase your insurance.

Comment: That takes my original proposed solution a step further and makes it more generic - good call. Paddle does seem rather a lot of code to solve that problem, but I guess you have to write something once you've chosen such a pithy library name.